# SQLAlchemy Polymorphic Many-to-many Relationship

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, polymorphism, relation

Does SQLAlchemy provide a convenient pattern to associate multiple classes with another class using a single table? For example, making the classes “Post“ and “Video” *taggable* by using a polymorphic many-to-many relationship with a “Tag” class?

I am familiar with the implementation of [many-to-many polymorphic relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations) in the Laravel PHP framework. This implementation uses a `type` field in the joining table to distinguish between classes “Post” and “Video".

Example:

```
posts
    id - integer
    name - string

videos
    id - integer
    name - string

tags
    id - integer
    name - string

taggables
    tag_id - integer
    taggable_id - integer
    taggable_type - string
```

I couldn’t find anything similar for SQLAlchemy. To my understanding, [Polymorphism in SQLalchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/inheritance.html) is limited to patterns for class inheritance. Similarly, the [association object pattern](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object) only seems to allow relationships between 2 classes.

Are polymorphic patterns like my example above recommended? Or is it generally better to define a many-to-many relationship with “Tag” for each class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can absolutely implement this with sqlalchemy.

Please read [Examples: Generic Associations](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/examples.html#module-examples.generic_associations) section of the documentation for various options.

The one you are looking for is shown in [`discriminator_on_association`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/_modules/examples/generic_associations/discriminator_on_association.html) code snippet.

Comment: This is a good start, but instead of re-using a 'taggable' it always recreates instead of re-using one that might already exist for the same tag name.